# How to make a __getitem__ method that allows list[][] indexing (2D)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a **getitem** method where I can use [][] to get an element from and array I have made. The method I came across is this:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
        x, y = item 
        return self.twoDim[x][y]
```

The problem with this is that I only can access the array by using a tuple, like array[1,0]. What I want is to be able to do this: array[1][0].

Im not sure how to pass these two arguments inside the **getitem** method since it only can take one at a time.

Any tips on how to make it work? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, two pairs of square brackets mean twice indexes, so `array[1][0]` is equivalent to:

```
array.__getitem__(1).__getitem__(0)
```

After one index, your `twoDim` can return the object that can be indexed again, so if the index has only one element, you can apply it to `twoDim` directly:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    if not isinstance(item, tuple):
        return self.twoDim[item]
    x, y = item
    return self.twoDim[x][y]
```